# Can't get php array value

Tags: php, arrays

Maybe I've spent too long on this. I have this code

```
$requestHeaders = getallheaders();
$authorizationHeader = $requestHeaders["authToken"];

print_r($requestHeaders);
echo $authorizationHeader;

// check that a auth header was sent
if ($authorizationHeader == null) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "No authorization header sent";
    exit();
}
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [Host] => localhost
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Cookie] => pma_collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci; pma_lang=en
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [authToken] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
    [Accept] => */*
    [Accept-Language] => en-us
    [Authorization] => Basic Og==
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [User-Agent] => CocoaRestClient/11 CFNetwork/720.3.9 Darwin/14.3.0 (x86_64)
)
No authorization header sent
```

Why can't I seam to get the auth-Token value out of the array??

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/TY76LIBx) the problem. Are you sure there is no other code in between the posted lines which may unset the variable?

Comment: Yes - I'm starting to think it is due to the fact that I'm using the built in php developer (php -S localhost:80) server and not apache. I will try to see if it works with apache

Comment: It worked when using apache. So strange... I don't even see why it would make a difference...

Comment: @JacobBenjaminCholewa "why it would make a difference" --- any chance you checked http://php.net/getallheaders ?

Comment: You can't send headers after output happened (print_r)

Comment: @hek2mgl This is not related to response headers at all. This is for retrieving request headers. These values should also be available through `$_SERVER`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Since when request headers are available via `$_SERVER`? Retrieving them depends on SAPI. For apache2 there is `getallheaders()` and this is what OP is using. Then he is issuing a `print_r()` and `echo` and after that a `header()`. The `header()` function cannot work there since there was already output happening. This is what my comment were addressing.

Comment: @JacobBenjaminCholewa You should set error reporting to E_ALL (for instance by using `error_reporting(-1)`) so you will be warned if code does not work as expected. In this case, as @hek2mgl mentioned, your `header()` cannot be sent because output has already been started. If you set error reporting to `-1`, you will be warned by PHP.

Comment: @hek2mgl Since it was introduced, really. Most HTTP request headers are available in $_SERVER, prefixed with HTTP_ (including custom headers such as X-Foo). Authorization is however not one of the headers included there (as it is processed by PHP into the PHP_AUTH_-keys in $_SERVER), so the SAPI specific functions (where getallheaders() has been extended to also work with FastCGI) is necessary to get the raw format of the header.

Comment: I solved this deploying on a LAMP stack instead. I was using the built-in development server in PHP when posting the question. I haven't figured out why it didn't work. It was very strange, but I don't want to waste anymore time on it :-)